# Why `it1++` works, but `it1=it1+1` does not, where it1 is iterator of list container

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

Given a `std::list` iterator called `it`, `it1++` is equivalent to `it1=it1+1`. So why then does `it1++` work fine, but `it1=it1+1` is giving an error in the below code?

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> l1{19, 2, 3, 21, 5, 19, 7, 11};
    std::list<int>::iterator it1;

    std::cout << "1st\n";
    it1 = l1.begin();
    it1++;
    it1 = it1 + 1; // This giving error
}
```

**Output**

```
Invalid operands to binary expression
 ('std::list<int>::iterator' (aka '_List_iterator<int>') and 'int')
```

Comment: @Bathsheba At a guess, some of the downvoting might be because the question started with code (I've now rectified that.), which typically is a bad sign indicating that the asker has not thought through the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Re: "`it1++` is equivalent to `it1=it1+1`” -- that's not the case. It's true for built-in numeric types, but once overloaded operators come into play, there's no inherent connection between the two operators. Iterators for `std::list` are **forward** iterators; they do not have an `operator+`, but they do have an `operator++`.

Edit, elaboration:

A **forward** iterator let’s you move forward in a sequence. To do that, it provides two overloads of `operator++`, so that you can write `it++` and `++it`. [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) provides forward iterators.

A **bidirectional** iterator let’s you move forward and backward in a sequence. In addition to the operations provided by forward iterators, it provides two overloads of `operator--`, so that you can write `it--` and `--it`. [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) provides bidirectional iterators.

A **random access** iterator let’s you move to arbitrary places in the sequence. In addition to this operations provided by bidirectional iterators, it provides an overload of `operator+` so that you can write `it + 3`. It also provides an overload of `operator[]` so that `it[n]` is equivalent to `*(it + n)`. [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) provides random access iterators.

Comment: Can you please change `operator—` to `operator--`, I can't request an edit with that few changes. It might confuse.

Comment: @thomas.st -- thanks for pointing that one out. My iPad insists on making that change; I fixed it everywhere else, and missed that one. Good thing my main system isn't that smart.